# ArcPy Slope Script - Trouble Saving

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, slope

I have an ArcPy script that applies the slope function to raster files in ArcGIS. I tried running the script with two raster files in the table of contents, and the script runs, but only saves one layer and loads it into the table of contents. I think that the script is overwriting, and only saving the last file.
Here is my script:

[image: ArcPy Slope Script]

Comment: you didn't put anything inside the parentheses. I think it should be outSlope.save(outputLayer) after outputLayer = "C:\DEM Files\SOMENAME"

Answer (score 1):

How about this ...
**EDIT:** This actually works now. It adds both layers at the bottom.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
#comment
env.workspace = "C:\DEM Files"
outWorkspace = "C:\DEM files\OUTPUT"
MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD, "Layers")[0]
# Not sure what this line I skipped is doing for you
# rasters = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(MXD, "", df) #don't do this
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
n=0
for layer in rasters:
    n+=1
    # took out inRaster variable and used layer directly
    outMeasurement = "PERCENT_RISE"
    zFactor = 1
    outSlope = Slope(layer, outMeasurement, zFactor)
    outLayer = str(outWorkspace) + "\\SLP" + str(n)
    outSlope.save(outLayer)
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(outLayer)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
MXD.save()
del MXD
```

Comment: I received the message: "Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 7)" (referring to rasters = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(MXD, "", df))

Comment: I was just re-typing the code from your screenshot. Try changing that line to this (from your previous question ;-)
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIFF")

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same message referring to that same line.

Comment: Ok well I needed to close parentheses on the line with df =  arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD, "Layers")[0]
Perhaps that was the line with the problem. I'm not getting any error on the line with ListRasters in it! Try it now.

Comment: It didn't do anything at all this time. It didn't run and it didn't give me any error messages.

Comment: did you check your output workspace? I think you can run this without the MXD and it should work fine. You aren't adding the layers to your MXD but they should be created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18263/discussion-between-jbchurchill-and-amoore9984).

Comment: I edited my answer. If you add the folder "OUTPUT" inside of "DEM Files", this should work now.